# Why $4$ is a QR modulo $13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the table of quadratic residues modulo $13$, $1^2\equiv 1\pmod {13}$, while $12^2\equiv 1\pmod {13}$.

It is stated that the full list of QR modulo $13$ is $\{1,3,4,9,10,12\}$

The definition given below, and the examples above suggests that the below definition is unclear and may be wrong:
A nonzero number that is congruent to a square modulo p is called
a quadratic residue modulo p. A number that is not congruent to a
square modulo p is called a (quadratic) non-residue modulo p. We
abbreviate these long expressions by saying that a quadratic residue is
a QR and a quadratic non-residue is an NR. A number that is congruent
to $0$ modulo p is neither a residue nor a non-residue.

I feel that the correct definition should be:
A nonzero number that can occur as square modulo $p$ is called
a quadratic residue modulo $p$, else non-residue modulo $p$.

The reason is that the given definition seems to imply that the number (let, $x$) and any other integer's (in the set $\{0,\cdots,p-1\}$, let $y$) square (i.e., $y^2$) have the same residue modulo $p$. By that implication, it is not correct, even if take (apart from $1\equiv 1\pmod {13}$) that $3\equiv 9\equiv 3 \pmod {13}$, as the same does not apply to $4,10,12.$

Comment: "congruent to **a** square", not "congruent to **its** square". The given definition is correct; you just misinterpreted it.

Comment: I corrected the error, which still not makes it clear, as the error was more of typo.

Comment: There is no error, I'm saying that you simply misinterpreted the definition. The two definitions you wrote down are saying the same thing.

Comment: $4$ is congruent to a square, namely $2^2$. Ergo, $4$ is a quadratic residue. What's the problem?

Comment: Kenny Lau's first comment seems to be the best explanation of the misunderstaning. It is one of grammar/reading comprehension. Here *a square* means *the square of some element.*  **Any** element will do.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Your first comment complicates, as the book has further definition : $(p-b)^2\equiv b^2\pmod {p}$. Here, (i) $p=13, b=2, p-b=11$ leading to $4\equiv 11\pmod {13}$ which is reflected as $4$ being QR of $11$. While if (ii) $p=13, b=4, p-b=9$ leading to $16\equiv 3 \equiv 9\pmod {13}$. Both are true, but need help to comprehend.

Comment: It is true that $(p-b)^2\equiv b^2\pmod p$ (by the way: that's a fact, not a definition). But how do you conclude that $4\equiv11\pmod{13}$ from that?? That's patently false. With $p=13, b=2, p-b=11$ you get that $2^2\equiv11^2\pmod{13}$. Or
$4\equiv 121\pmod{13}$. That is true because $4-121$ is divisible by $13$. Similarly $3\not\equiv9\pmod{13}$, but $3\equiv 9^2\pmod{13}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for helping me understand better. Also, have a seemingly silly doubt regarding your first comment, which states that $4$ is congruent to a square, i.e. of $2^2$. Unable to comprehend it; as how are other congruent numbers $3,10,12$ being congruent to any square of any integer. Sorry, if silly, but had to ask.

Comment: $3\equiv 4^2\pmod{13}$, $12\equiv5^2\pmod{13}$, $10\equiv6^2\pmod{13}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, the notation is so that the interpretation has to be as given by you. But, each QR is for two values, say there is $12\equiv 8^2\pmod {13}$ too. However, it seems for later pages.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I request some hint for my last comment, i.e. why each QR serves two values (one of which, may be same as it), and additional issue is why the table of QRs is symmetrical about the center half. The book seemingly draws table of QRs for some modulo, and then concludes $b^2 =  (p-b)^2\pmod p$. But, can there be a better way to prove it, which is not dependent on table construction and derive based on that. Is it just that need the table first, and then see that $b^2\equiv p^2+b^2-2pb\pmod p$, which is the scheme used in the book.